# get set expected in c#

Tags: c#, get, set, accessor

i have console application in that i create class 
then i create some functions and i call that function in program class

one is

```
public class student
    {
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public List<int> scores { get; set; }
    }
public  void example2
     {
         List<student> std = new List<student>
        {
            new student {Lastname="ALI",scores=new List<int>{97, 72, 81, 60}},
            new student{Lastname="abc",scores=new List<int>{75, 84, 91, 39}},
            new student {Lastname="shan",scores=new List<int>{12,34,6,23,434}},
            new student{Lastname="ahmad",scores=new List<int>{34,23,45,34}}

        };
        var sq = from stud in std
                 from scor in stud.scores
                 where scor > 90
                 select new { last = stud.Lastname, scor };

        Console.WriteLine("Scorequery");
        foreach (var stdquery in sq)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Score:{1}", stdquery.last, stdquery.scor);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

another example

```
public  void example2
        {
        int[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var q1 = from q2 in numbers
                 where q2 < 5
                 select q2;
        foreach (int i in q1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + "");

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

now error occur on int[]  is 
    A get or set accessor expected
where as i create get set public 
same with another function and error occur on this line

```
List<student> std = new List<student>
```

and another function on this line

```
 char[] uppercase = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
```

Comment: I don't know if this is just a typo when putting the code in there, but neither  of the example2 method declarations have parenthesis.  They should look like this: public void example2 ()  not public void example2

Answer (score 3):

You missed the parentheses after your `example2` function definition name. It should be `public void example2()` and not `public  void example2`.

When you define a method, you need to place parentheses after the method name. When you define an entity with braces but without parentheses, the compiler thinks that you are defining a property, like you do in the class `student`.

Even if you don't have any parameters for the method, the definition *must* contain parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, methods must have parameter lists in parantheses, i.e.

```
public void example()
```

instead of

```
public void example
```

Without the parantheses, the compiler thinks you were creating a property and thus expects a getter or setter.